# tabs not changing title in tabviewcontroller

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a TabViewController that was auto generated by xamarin studio:
[image]

Ive changed the 2 tabs to say `Football` and `Basketball` but when I run the app the changes dont take place:

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried changing the Title of the view contained in each tab?

Comment: @Jason That fixed the title, but did not fix the image. Is there a param to change the image? Why does changing it in `xcode` do nothing?

Comment: I've only done that in code, not IB.

Comment: @Jason so how do you change the image then?

Comment: @Deekor, `TabBarItem.Image` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically set the `Title` and `Image`

```
Title = "Football";
TabBarItem.Image =  new UIImage("football.png");
```